# Pylint recursively for a given filename

Tags: python, django, pylint

I have a Django project and I'm working on Pylinting my way through it.

I have a couple situations where I'd like to be able to recursively find all files with a given name and pylint them differently (using different options). For example, I'd like to set different options for pylinting urls.py and admin.py

The following works for 1 directory..

```
pylint ./project_name/*/urls.py
```

But I'd like to make that `*` recursive... so that it drills into sub directories.

Any way to achieve that?

---

**Update**
I'd also like them all to run as a single pylint output, not sequentially

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on your operating system, you could use:

```
find project_name -name urls.py | xargs pylint
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need it to... it looks like it's running them all as a single pylint execution

Comment: As a side note, it is important not to strip any `__init__.py` file from the paths returned by find (so as to get the module parsed instead) with this solution, or you may get `duplicate-code` warnings should you have other files in your modules.

Answer (score 4):

Try with find:

```
find ./project_name/ -name "urls.py" -exec pylint '{}' \;
```

If you want to run multiple files in a single call to `pylint`:

```
find ./project_name/ -name "urls.py" -exec pylint '{}' +
```

Comment: This worked great but it ran them one at a time... not something I mentioned in my post but I need them all to run as a single pylint. I'll update the question. Still +1-ing you

Comment: @Brant - You can do this with find. I've edited the answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

- Get all python files (recursive)
- Pass them all at once to pylint (from answer by Robin)
- Show output in console and put it in a file

`find . -name "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 pylint 2>&1 | tee err_pylint.rst~`